# How can we paginate a big hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a pure ruby hash like the following one:

```
   "1875": {
        "child1": {
            "field1": 1875,
            "field2": "Test1"
        },
        "child2": {
           "field1": "value1",
           "field2": "value2"
        }

    },
    "1959": {
         "child1": {
            "field1": 1875,
            "field2": "Test1"
        },
        "child2": {
           "field1": "value1",
           "field2": "value2"
        }
    }
```

I have so many keys that follow the above structure that I want to paginate it.

I have tried the following code:

```rb
@records = @records.t_a.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

But it is returning me all the elements in an array, like this:

```
    ["1875", {
        "child1": {
            "field1": 1875,
            "field2": "Test1"
        },
        "child2": {
           "field1": "value1",
           "field2": "value2"
        }

    }
   ]
   ["1959", {
         "child1": {
            "field1": 1875,
            "field2": "Test1"
        },
        "child2": {
           "field1": "value1",
           "field2": "value2"
        }
    }
   ]
```

Comment: can you provide more details of what you are trying to do? what is your object a Hash and why do you need to paginate it (in other words why are you rendering a Hash sequentially)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that a Hash is a dictionary-like collection and order shouldn't mater. So if you need to use pagination most likely a hash is the wrong data structure to use and you should use something like an array.

`@records.t_a.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)` returns an array because you are converting the hash to array with [`to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-to_a). Depending what you are using the hash/pagination for this may be enough. For example, to display a the returned records assuming there is a function for printing child:

```
@records.t_a.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).each |key, value| do
  <h1><%= book.title %></h1>
  <p>print_child(value)</p>
```

If you really want a hash, you can convert the Array back to a hash:

`Hash[@records.t_a.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)]`